# Couple applying for UK tourist visa in separate countries

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

My husband and I intend to travel to the UK end of June 2017. While we are aware of the application process and the documents needed, the predicament that we are in is that we are in two countries.

My husband resides in the UAE and will be making his application there. I am in India; my UAE visa was cancelled, and it will take a while to get a new UAE resident visa. So, I will be submitting my application in India.

Does my husband need to mention that I will enter the UK with him? There is a section in the form that asks if the spouse will accompany the applicant.

Comment: If you will be accompanying him, the only correct answer is **yes**

Answer (score 1):

> Does my husband need to mention that I will enter the UK with him?

If you will be accompanying him, the only correct answer is **yes**. The generally accepted rule with immigration and visa applications is tell the truth, particularly when there is little ambiguity. In this case the truth is the correct answer which is yes. I don't believe I need to cite references to back this up.